Making an add button in VB.net with MySql
Once i click the add button it states You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near Id, BookTitle, Author, YearPublished) value ('1','1232','king','Ryan','2024)'at line 1
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class AdminInterface

    Dim sqlConn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlRd As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sqlDt As New DataTable
    Dim DTA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlQuery As String

    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim username As String = "root"
    Dim password As String = "202015"
    Dim database As String = "myconnector"

    Private bitmap As Bitmap

    Private Sub updateTableBelow()

        sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";" + "database=" + database

        sqlConn.Open()
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM librarybook.librarybook;"

            sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            sqlDt.Load(sqlRd)
            sqlRd.Close()
            sqlConn.Close()
            Display1Book.DataSource = sqlDt

    End Sub
    Private Sub AddBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddBtn.Click
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";" + "database=" + database

        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlQuery = "Insert into librarybook.librarybook(no, Book Id, BookTitle, Author, YearPublished)
value('" & SearchTxT.Text & "','" & BookIdTxT.Text & "','" & BookTitleTxt.Text & "','" & AuthorTxt.Text & "','" & YearPublishedTxT.Text & "')"

            sqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn)
            sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            sqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, " My Sql connector", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Finally
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

        updateTableBelow()
    End Sub
End Class

I tried using the try and catch func but it didn't work.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Why do you call ExecuteReader? You should call ExecuteNonQuery or something.

It's VALUES, not value, and column names with spaces have to be quoted: MySQL: how to quote or escape field names?.

Also, column names which are reserved words must be quoted: Keywords and Reserved Words.

And as a general point, make sure to keep names consistent in style: "Book Id" has a space between words, but "BookTitle" and "YearPublished" do not. I suggest using the latter form.

Avoid connection objects with application or class/module level scope. Declare a connection and command where you use it, using the Using construct so that the .NET runtime will properly dispose of it.

Incorporating information from the comments, and adding some other comments, you could use something like this:
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    'TODO: Store these values in a config file.
    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim database As String = "myconnector"
    'TODO: Add a user to MySql to avoid using the "root" account.
    Dim username As String = "root"
    'TODO: Investigate how to store the password securely.
    Dim password As String = "202015"

    Public Function ConnStr() As String
        Return New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {
            .Server = server,
            .Database = database,
            .UserID = username,
            .Password = password}.ToString()

    End Function

    Private Sub AddBook()
        'TODO: Make the column name formats consistent.
        Dim sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO librarybook.librarybook(`no`, `Book Id`, `BookTitle`, `Author`, `YearPublished`)
                               VALUES(@no, @id, @title, @author, @pubyear)"

        Using conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnStr())

            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@no", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String, .Value = SearchTxT.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@id", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String, .Value = BookIdTxT.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@title", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String, .Value = BookTitleTxt.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@author", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String, .Value = AuthorTxt.Text})
            'TODO: Use the appropriate MySql type for the published year.
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@pubyear", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Year, .Value = YearPublishedTxT.Text})

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddBtn.Click
        AddBook()
        UpdateTableBelow()

    End Sub

End Class

The MySqlConnectionStringBuilder will take care of any quoting/escaping necessary for things like spaces in usernames or strange characters in passwords.
If you store the connection parameters in a config file, you could write some code so that the user can easily change them without having to recompile the program.
It makes it easier to debug and maintain the program if you split it into smaller pieces, hence the addition of the AddBook sub. It would be better to pass the "no", "id", "title", etc., as parameters to AddBook instead of it getting them from the controls.
Some kind of input validation should be added—for example, you might want to make sure that the year of publication is a sensible value.
